# Unsupervised feature learning from raw text as a previous step for clasification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I have a corpus of 2500 opinions, is it posible to use scikit´s restricted boltzmann machine implementation to extract a feature vector as a previous step to a classification task?. What aproach do i need to follow in order to use a restricted boltzman machine for text classification?, do i need to label my data to classify?

Comment: The question is strange (the answer I'd offer is "yes, you probably can, but this is not the mainstream approach, try PCA first instead").

Also note that your chances of getting enthusiastic responses might be higher at http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Yes, im exploring alternative aproaches. Any idea of how to label the data?, Thank you.

Comment: In general, 2500 is a dataset size small enough for manual labeling.

If you come up with an automatic method for labeling your dataset the problem of "learning the classification model" will become somewhat obsolete (because your labeling model will already be the correct classification model).

Comment: You probably want to start with using a CountVectorizer or TfidfVectorizer. If you want a fancy embedding, I'd recommend using Word2Vec, which can be used via the gensim package. I don't know what you expect from using an RBM.

Comment: Thank you @AndreasMueller. Before posting this question, i all ready started with the Tdidf representation with scikit. I expect not to use the "traditional" feature learning aproach or making n-grams, bigrams, bow, etc. In an unsupervised way i just want to avoid the task of using the before said aproaches.

Comment: why? Also, have you looked into word2vec?

Comment: I didn´t know about word2vect. Im checking it up. Thanks @AndreasMueller

Comment: The first question is what are you trying to classify?

Comment: @DVolsky it´s a sentiment analisys task, im trying to classfy raw text as positive, negative or neutral.